# Backpropagation Through Hidden Layers in Neural Network Implementation

Tags: c, machine-learning, math, neural-network, backpropagation

I've been implementing a neural network in C and have come across a problem with backpropagation through the hidden layers. My back propagation function works correctly for a single layer network (i.e., a network with no hidden layer), but it seems to fail when I try to back propagate the error through one or more hidden layers. The loss is computed correctly for the first iteration, but then increases rapidly to reach infinity.

Here's my current implementation of the backpropagation algorithm:

```
void backpropagation(NNetwork* network) {
Layer* outputLayer = network->layers[network->layerCount - 1];

// for each output
for(int outputIndex = 0; outputIndex < 1; outputIndex++) {
    
    // TODO: Implement this.
    double totalCost = 0.0f;

    // the output layer's step
    int layerIndex = network->layerCount - 1;
    Layer* currentLayer = network->layers[layerIndex];
    Vector* dLoss_dInputs = createVector(currentLayer->weights->rows);

    for(int outputNeuronIndex = 0; outputNeuronIndex < outputLayer->neuronCount; outputNeuronIndex++) {
        Vector* predictions = network->data->trainingOutputs->data[outputIndex];
        double prediction = predictions->elements[outputNeuronIndex];

        double target = network->data->yValues->elements[outputIndex];
        double error =  target - prediction;
        error *= error;
        error *= 0.5;
        /* TODO: ABSTRACT THIS TO SUIT MULTIPLE LOSS FUNCTIONS  
           derivative of MSE is -1 * error, as:
           derivative of 1/2 * (value)^2 = 1/2 * 2(value) => 2/2 * (value) = 1 * value
        
           Using the chain rule for differentiation (f(g(x)) = df(g(x)) * g'(x)), we then multiply this by the derivative of the inner function,
           g(x) = (desired - predicted), with respect to 'predicted', which gives g'(x) = -1
           Therefore, the derivative of the MSE with respect to 'predicted' is: f'(g(predicted)) * g'(predicted) = (desired - predicted) * -1 = predicted - desired
        */
        double dLoss_dOutput = -1 * error;

        double dOutput_dWeightedSum = currentLayer->weightedSums->elements[outputNeuronIndex] > 0 ? 1 : 0.01;
        double dLoss_dWeightedSum = dLoss_dOutput * dOutput_dWeightedSum;

        // dLoss/dInputN = Σ [(dLoss/dOutput_i) * (dOutput_i/dWeightedSum_i) * w_i->N]
        // dLoss/dInputN = Σ [dLoss_dOutput * dOutput_dWeightedSum * weight]

        for(int weightIndex = 0; weightIndex < currentLayer->weights->rows; weightIndex++) {
            
            double dWeightedSum_dWeight = matrixToVector(network->layers[layerIndex]->input)->elements[weightIndex];
            
            double dLoss_dWeight = dLoss_dWeightedSum * dWeightedSum_dWeight;
            
            currentLayer->gradients->data[weightIndex]->elements[outputNeuronIndex] = dLoss_dWeight;                
        }

        for(int prevLayerNeuronIndex = 0; prevLayerNeuronIndex < network->layers[layerIndex - 1]->neuronCount; prevLayerNeuronIndex++) {
            double dLoss_dInputN = 0.0f;
            for(int weightColumnIndex = 0; weightColumnIndex < currentLayer->weights->columns; weightColumnIndex++) {
                dLoss_dInputN += (dLoss_dOutput * dOutput_dWeightedSum) * currentLayer->weights->data[prevLayerNeuronIndex]->elements[weightColumnIndex];
            }
            printf("DLOSS_DINPUTN: %f \n", dLoss_dInputN);
            dLoss_dInputs->elements[prevLayerNeuronIndex] = dLoss_dInputN;
        }
    }

    for(layerIndex = network->layerCount - 2; layerIndex >= 0; layerIndex --) {
        currentLayer = network->layers[layerIndex];
        Vector* dLoss_dInputsHidden = createVector(currentLayer->weights->rows);
        for(int neuronIndex = 0; neuronIndex < currentLayer->neuronCount; neuronIndex++) {
            double dLoss_dOutput = dLoss_dInputs->elements[neuronIndex];

            double dOutput_dWeightedSum = currentLayer->weightedSums->elements[neuronIndex] > 0 ? 1 : 0.01;
            double dLoss_dWeightedSum = dLoss_dOutput * dOutput_dWeightedSum;


            for(int weightIndex = 0; weightIndex < currentLayer->weights->rows; weightIndex++) {
                
                double dWeightedSum_dWeight = matrixToVector(network->layers[layerIndex]->input)->elements[weightIndex];
                
                double dLoss_dWeight = dLoss_dWeightedSum * dWeightedSum_dWeight;
                
                currentLayer->gradients->data[weightIndex]->elements[neuronIndex] = dLoss_dWeight;
                
            }

            if(layerIndex == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            for(int prevLayerNeuronIndex = 0; prevLayerNeuronIndex < network->layers[layerIndex - 1]->neuronCount; prevLayerNeuronIndex++) {
                double dLoss_dInputN = 0.0f;
                for(int weightColumnIndex = 0; weightColumnIndex < currentLayer->weights->columns; weightColumnIndex++) {
                    dLoss_dInputN += (dLoss_dOutput * dOutput_dWeightedSum) * currentLayer->weights->data[prevLayerNeuronIndex]->elements[weightColumnIndex];
                }
                
                dLoss_dInputsHidden->elements[prevLayerNeuronIndex] = dLoss_dInputN;
            }
        }
        freeVector(dLoss_dInputs);
        dLoss_dInputs = dLoss_dInputsHidden;

    }
}}
```

My network structure is as follows:

- Input layer with a certain number of neurons.
- One or more hidden layers, each with a certain number of neurons.
- Output layer with a single neuron.

Any help or guidance?

Comment: Try computing finite difference approximations to the gradient, i.e. just (change in loss function)/(change in each free parameter), and compare that to the computed gradient -- my guess is that it will show which terms are computed correctly and which aren't.

Comment: It shows that some are close while others are a large magnitude away .

Comment: Well, that's a good start. Probably you're already looking for a pattern in the incorrect terms. It might be possible to drill further into the incorrect terms and see if there are intermediate results you can look at -- my guess is that again you'll see some of the intermediate results are correct and some aren't.

Comment: Well one of the problems is this line: double dLoss_dOutput = -1 * error;  which should be double dLoss_dOutput = -1 * (target - prediction);

Comment: Is there a mixup with the definition of MSE? If MSE = (1/n) (sum of squared errors) then maybe the 1 should be a 2. Maybe the existing code is effectively assuming MSE = 1/2 times (1/n) (sum of squared errors).

Comment: @RobertDodier after fixing the dLoss_dOutput calculation I hand calculated all values for a fixed set of inputs and weights and biases and found that I had some problems with indexing in the inner loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems was this line: double dLoss_dOutput = -1 * error; which should be double dLoss_dOutput = -1 * (target - prediction);

and I had some indexing issues. If you want to see the fixed version of the code: https://github.com/MevlutArslan/neural-networks-from-scratch